# ES6 Arrow function is changing the scope of this in Meteor.publish

Tags: javascript, meteor, ecmascript-6, meteor-publications

So I been started using ES6 in `Meteor`, but apparently if you try to use `Meteor.publish` syntax with an arrow function, `this.userId` is undefined, while if you use it with a regular `function(){}` `this.userId` works perfectly, Im assuming is a kind of transpiler process that assign a different this, to `userId` but is just a guess, does anyone knows what really is happening?

```
Meteor.startup(function() {
    Meteor.publish("Activities", function() { //with function
        console.log(this.userId); //TS8vTE3z56LLcaCb5
    });
});

Meteor.startup(function() {
    Meteor.publish("Activities", ()=> { //with arrow function
        console.log(this.userId); //undefined
    });
});
```

Comment: From MDN: *"An arrow function expression (also known as fat arrow function) has a shorter syntax compared to function expressions and **lexically binds the `this` value**.'* https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: @FelixKling how this is a duplicate question?

Comment: It exaplains how `this` in arrow functions works.

Comment: @FelixKling arrow function is specific in the context of ES6, while I understand your point I think that answer is not broad enough to understand that concept from Meteor perspective, you should reevaluate your decision IMHO.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This isn't a transpilation error, it's a [feature](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Lexical_this) of arrow functions. The arrow function automatically sets the context of the function body to the contexts here it was created, in this case the callback to `Meteor.publish`. This prevents Meteor from rebinding the context of your listener function.

From the Meteor [publish docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_publish):

> Inside the function, this is the publish handler object

If you want things to work properly you will need to use the "old-school" function syntax to allow Meteor to set the context properly.

Comment: It's called "arrow function", not "fat-arrow function".

Comment: You are Completely right :) although there is a strong colloquial weight behind fat-arrow. I will update! Thanks

Comment: "An arrow function expression (also known as fat arrow function)..." -MDN